# convert UIImage to NSData

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, nsdata

I am using this code in my app which will help me to send a image.

However, I have an image view with an image. I have no file in appbundle but have the image in my side. How can I change the below code ? Can anyone tell me how can I convert `myimage` to `NSData` ?

```
// Attach an image to the email
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"rainy" ofType:@"jpg"];
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
[picker addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:@"rainy"];
```

Comment: UIImageJPEGRepresentation,UIImagePNGRepresentation both return nsdata of the image.....

Answer (score 289, accepted):

Try one of the following, depending on your image format:

> UIImageJPEGRepresentation
>
> Returns the data for the specified image in JPEG format.

```
NSData * UIImageJPEGRepresentation (
   UIImage *image,
   CGFloat compressionQuality
);
```

> UIImagePNGRepresentation
>
> Returns the data for the specified image in PNG format

```
NSData * UIImagePNGRepresentation (
   UIImage *image
);
```

[Here the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/images_and_pdf?language=objc).

EDIT:

if you want to access the raw bytes that make up the UIImage, you could use this approach:

```
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGImageGetDataProvider(image.CGImage);
NSData* data = (id)CFBridgingRelease(CGDataProviderCopyData(provider));
const uint8_t* bytes = [data bytes];
```

This will give you the low-level representation of the image RGB pixels.
(Omit the `CFBridgingRelease` bit if you are not using ARC).

Comment: Is there a way to just get the data in whatever format it is already in?

Comment: Xcode suggests me to use `(id)CFBridgingRelease(CGDataProviderCopyData(provider))` to take the ownership of `CDataRef` returned by `CGDataProviderCopyData` in ARC.

Comment: @mostruash: thanks, I have modified my answer to take into account your suggestion.

Comment: @sergio I'm not experienced with non-ARC Obj-C and I wonder if releasing `data` would be enough or if there would still be a memory leak.

Comment: @mostruash: in non-ARC case, there is no concept of ownership; the programmer should ensure that each object be released for any retain it received. In the present case, by releasing `data` you would ensure the object is properly deallocated: `CGDataProviderCopyData` gives you a retain count of `1`; be releasing the object, you make it to be dealloc-ed.

Comment: Note that imageFlags (like imageOrientation) get lost when using UIImagePNGRepresentation. That's why UIImageJPEGRepresentation is preferred

Comment: This won't help. The property CIImage is only set if it was initialized with imageWithCIImage:. Also this isn't directly the used data but rather another image representation object.

Answer (score 166):

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage.image);
```

Comment: I am using this line but this is very slow

Comment: Note that imageFlags (like imageOrientation) get lost when using UIImagePNGRepresentation. That's why UIImageJPEGRepresentation is preferred.

Answer (score 26):

If you have an image inside a UIImageView , e.g. "myImageView", you can do the following:

Convert your image using UIImageJPEGRepresentation() or UIImagePNGRepresentation() like this:

```
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImageView.image);
//or
NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImageView.image, 0.8);
//The float param (0.8 in this example) is the compression quality 
//expressed as a value from 0.0 to 1.0, where 1.0 represents 
//the least compression (or best quality).
```

You can also put this code inside a GCD block and execute in another thread, showing an UIActivityIndicatorView during the process ...

```
//*code to show a loading view here*

dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.my.queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{ 

    NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImageView.image);
    //some code....

    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //*code to hide the loading view here*
    });
});
```

Answer (score 24):

Create the reference of image....

```
UIImage *rainyImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rainy.jpg"];
```

displaying  image in image view... *imagedisplay* is reference of imageview:

```
imagedisplay.image = rainyImage;
```

convert it into `NSData` by passing `UIImage` reference and provide compression quality in float values:

```
NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(rainyImage, 0.9);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Solution in Swift 4**

```
extension UIImage {
    var data : Data? {
      return cgImage?.dataProvider?.data as Data?
    }
}
```

Comment: How is the `cgImage.dataProvider` data encoded? It seems to be different from the data of `UIImagePNGRepresentation` and `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` because it cannot be used to create an image like so `UIImage(data: imageData)`.

Comment: @Manuel Not sure. I just converted the syntax from Sergio 's answer.  Sergio would probably know better.

Comment: @Manuel I'm assuming because it's using CoreGraphics API it's giving a lower-level data representation of the image than what `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` provides. But I believe this solution preserves the original encoding format that the image was in and doesn't re-encode it.

Answer (score 1):

Use if-let block with Data to prevent app crash & safe execution of code, as function UIImagePNGRepresentation returns an optional value.

```
if let img = UIImage(named: "TestImage.png") {
    if let data:Data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img) {
       // Handle operations with data here...         
    }
}
```

> Note: **Data** is Swift 3 class. Use Data instead of NSData with
>   Swift 3

Generic image operations (like png & jpg both):

```
if let img = UIImage(named: "TestImage.png") {  //UIImage(named: "TestImage.jpg")
        if let data:Data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img) {
               handleOperationWithData(data: data)     
        } else if let data:Data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 1.0) {
               handleOperationWithData(data: data)     
        }
}

*******
func handleOperationWithData(data: Data) {
     // Handle operations with data here...
     if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
        // Use image...
     }
}
```

By using extension:

```
extension UIImage {

    var pngRepresentationData: Data? {
        return UIImagePNGRepresentation(img)
    }

    var jpegRepresentationData: Data? {
        return UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self, 1.0)
    }
}

*******
if let img = UIImage(named: "TestImage.png") {  //UIImage(named: "TestImage.jpg")
      if let data = img.pngRepresentationData {
              handleOperationWithData(data: data)     
      } else if let data = img.jpegRepresentationData {
              handleOperationWithData(data: data)     
     }
}

*******
func handleOperationWithData(data: Data) {
     // Handle operations with data here...
     if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
        // Use image...
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void) imageConvert
{
     UIImage *snapshot = self.myImageView.image;
     [self encodeImageToBase64String:snapshot];
}    


call this method for image convert in base 64 
    -(NSString *)encodeImageToBase64String:(UIImage *)image
    {
        return [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
    }
```