# Saving Data in ApplicationDidEnterBackground & Loading

Tags: ios, xcode, load, save, appdelegate

**AppDelegate.h file**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize viewController = _viewController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    self.viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [self.viewController loadData];
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    [self.viewController saveData];
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    [self.viewController loadData];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    [self.viewController saveData];
}

@end
```

**LoadData & SaveData Code(ViewController.m)**

```
- (NSString *) getFilePath{
    NSArray *pathArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    return [[pathArray objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"saved.plist"];
}

- (void) saveData{
    NSArray *value = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[imageLoad image], [NSNumber numberWithInt:colorpick], [NSNumber numberWithInt:pdvalue], [NSNumber numberWithInt:iauto], nil];
    [value writeToFile:[self getFilePath] atomically:YES];
}

- (void) loadData{
    NSString *myPath = [self getFilePath];
    BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:myPath];


    if(fileExists){
        NSArray *values = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myPath];
        imageLoad.image = [values objectAtIndex:0];
        colorpick = [[values objectAtIndex:1] intValue];
        pdvalue = [[values objectAtIndex:2] intValue];
        iauto = [[values objectAtIndex:3] intValue];
    }
}
```

I wanted to save the image of the imageLoad, the value of int colorpick, pdvalue, and auto though the application is terminated, entered background, or the phone(simulator) is switched off. But, it doesn't load. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to retrieve the underlying NSData from the UIImage and save the NSData.

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6476959/287403

Then retrieve NSData and convert it back to an UIImage.

```
Objective-C

+ (UIImage *)imageWithData:(NSData *)data;
```

See [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiimage_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageWithData:)