# How to convert UIimage into NSData.?

Tags: ios, web-services, uiimage, nsdata

Iam getting an image Object from WebService and I don't know what is the format of image. Than how to change this image object into NSData. Please help. Thanks

Comment: You can't do anything if you don't know in what format you are getting your image from webservice..

Comment: You can see refer to


   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476929/convert-uiimage-to-nsdata  

It may help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(yourImage, 1.0);
```

or

```
NSData* data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(yourimage);
```

Answer (score 0):

Only simple one line will do it for you

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(yourImageView.image);
```