# How to get NSData representation of UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uigraphicscontext

I'm taking a "snapshot" of the image context in `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size, true, 0)` and eventually creating a `UIImage` using

```
var renderedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
```

However I need to get the NSData representation of this UIImage without using `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` or `UIImagePNGRepresentation` (because these produce files that are way larger than the original UIImage). How can I do this?

Comment: What image representation should the NSData contain?

Comment: FYI, you can reduce the size of the image by adding in another parameter `UIImageJPEGRepresentation(yourImage, 0.9f)`

Comment: @rmaddy it should be in jpeg. I don't want to reduce the quality though. If I save the exact same image to the Photos Album using `ALAssetsLibrary` the image size is almost 4 times smaller, but no compression seems to have occurred.

Comment: It must be compressing it if it's four times smaller.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "way larger" than the original UIImage. The data backing the UIImage object is at least as big as the data you would get by converting it into a `JPG`, and roughly equivalent to the data you would get by converting it to a `PNG`.

The rendered image will be twice the screen size in points, because you have rendered a retina screen into an image.

You can avoid this and render the image as non-retina by making your image context have a scale of 1:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size, true, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

> these produce files that are way larger than the original UIImage). How can I do this?

Image files contain compressed data, while NSData is raw i.e. not compressed. Therefore NSData will in about all cases be larger, when written into a file.

More info at another question: [convert UIImage to NSData](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6476929/113079)

Comment: Sorry I meant "way larger" than the image saved to the Photo Album using `ALAssetsLibrary`.